# Fast creation of 2D array from 1D array of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert the following 1D array of my class **Frames** to a 2D byte array (I need the 2D byte array for sending to a GPU, I cannot use jagged arrays, Lists, or other enumerables).

Right now, my conversion is very slow and stupid:

```
public byte[,] allBytes()
{
    byte[,] output = new byte[this.frameListSize, this.ySize * this.xSize];
    for (int y = 0; y < this.frameListSize; y++)
    {
        byte[] bits = this.frameList[y].getBytes();
        for (int x = 0; x < this.ySize * this.xSize; x++)
        {
            output[y, x] = bits[x];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

The snippets that define of frameList and Frame are below:

```
public Frame[] frameList;

public class Frame
{

  public byte[] bits;

  public byte[] getBytes()
  {
    return bits;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use .NET Framework 4 or higher, you can use [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for a first speeding up)

```
    public byte[,] allBytes()
    {
        int size1 = this.frameListSize;
        int size2 = this.ySize * this.xSize;
        byte[,] output = new byte[size1, size2];
        Parallel.For(0, size1, (y) =>
        {
            byte[] bits = this.frameList[y].getBytes();
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bits, 0, output, 0 + size2 * y, bits.Length);
        });
        return output;
    }
```

[Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is about 20 times faster than normal copying. Make sure bits.Length has the same value as size2. Otherwise you can run into errors

Comment: Yes, I am using .net 4.5.2, But I think the CPU usage is hurting my video frame grabber which is what is deliving all these bytes (I am getting buffer overflows when I do this in parallel with the fetching of the data). The resultant 2D byte array is [21, 1024x1024]

Comment: from the MSDN documentation you quote: ArgumentException 
The current Array does not have exactly one dimension.

Comment: Im sorry, its my fault. Then you have to use Block.Copy (changed in my answer)

Comment: That's a dramatic improvement. Thanks.